# http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException .. what's the reason

Tags: android, json, getjson

When run code gives this error in console. I use web services to get data from the json api's of the server.

What's the reason?

```
10-16 13:17:33.389: E/log_tag(651): Error in http connection android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-16 13:17:33.389: E/log_tag(651): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
10-16 13:17:33.399: E/log_tag(651): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Error occur when running this class

```
public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url) {

        // initialize
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        String error_text="";
        JSONObject j = null;

        // http post
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            HttpParams myParams = null;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);

            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            //System.out.println("Result = " + result);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            //jArray = new JSONObject(result);
            response_status = j.getString("response_status").toString().trim();

            if (response_status.equals("0")) {
                String getcustomer_id = j.getString("customer_id").toString().trim();
                String getPassword = j.getString("password").toString()
                        .trim();
                passData(getcustomer_id, getPassword);
            } else {
                String getcustomer_id = j.getString("response_status").toString()
                        .trim();
                String getPassword = j.getString("error_text").toString()
                        .trim();
                passData(getcustomer_id, getPassword);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return j;
    }

    private static void passData(String getcustomer_id, String getPassword) {
        id = getcustomer_id;
        password = getPassword;
    }
```

Comment: @Yicanis what for? NetworkOnMainThreadException - he don't catch this so response stream is null(NullPointerException), so string with json is null or empty(JSONException) ...

Comment: @Selvin The two other errors are occurring because of the first which states that there is an error in the connection, therefore he's converting null which would give a NullPointerException. By catching the error in the first place would work, however it would not fix the underlying problem which is there is an error in the connection. Unless he means to test a failed connection. Therefore I requested for some code :)

Answer (score 3):

This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Run your code in AsyncTask:

```
class GetJSONFromUrl extends AsyncTask<String, Void, RSSFeed> {

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    String error_text="";
    JSONObject j = null;

    protected void doInBackground(String... urls) {

    // http post
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        HttpParams myParams = null;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(myParams, 10000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(myParams, 10000);

        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
    }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        //System.out.println("Result = " + result);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        //jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        response_status = j.getString("response_status").toString().trim();

        if (response_status.equals("0")) {
            String getcustomer_id = j.getString("customer_id").toString().trim();
            String getPassword = j.getString("password").toString()
                    .trim();
            passData(getcustomer_id, getPassword);
        } else {
            String getcustomer_id = j.getString("response_status").toString()
                    .trim();
            String getPassword = j.getString("error_text").toString()
                    .trim();
            passData(getcustomer_id, getPassword);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
        super.onPostExecute(result)
    }
}
```

You can call this from anywhere in your code by using `new GetJSONFromUrl().execute(url);`.

The Network task needs to be done in `DoInBackground` thread because in versions above HoneyComb, you cannot perform Network tasks on `UIThread`. Here, `onPostExecute()` method is called after the Background thread completes its execution. You can access `UIThread` from `onPostExecute()`. So, simply write your networking code in the background thread and then you can perform tasks on your main thread in the `onPostExecute()`.

Hope this helps. Thanks.